# Delete entity when it has a optional foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, exception, ef-code-first

I have a model containing these classes:

[image]

`Curriculum` class has several `SessionTime`s and other classes use these entities.

The configuration classes for them are:

```
public class SessionAttendanceConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<SessionAttendance>
{
    public SessionAttendanceConfiguration()
    {
        HasOptional(x => x.Session)
            .WithMany(x => x.SessionAttendance)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

public class SessionTimeConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<SessionTime>
{
    public SessionTimeConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.ClassSessions)
            .WithOptional(x => x.SessionTime)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        HasMany(x => x.SessionAttendance)
            .WithOptional(x => x.Session)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

public class StudentAttendanceConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<StudentAttendance>
{
    public StudentAttendanceConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(x => x.SessionAttendances)
            .WithRequired()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }
}

public class ClassSessionConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ClassSession>
{
    public ClassSessionConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(x => x.EducationDay)
            .WithMany(x => x.Sessions)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        HasOptional(x => x.SessionTime)
            .WithMany(x => x.ClassSessions)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

public class CurriculumConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Curriculum>
{
    public CurriculumConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(x => x.Course)
            .WithOptional(x => x.Curriculum);
    }
}
```

When I want to delete a `Course` object, at first I load all the children and mark them as `Deleted`, and at the end remove that course from the context.

Something like this:

```
if (course.StudentAttendances.IsNullOrEmpty())   
     context.Entry(course).Collection(x => x.StudentAttendances);
// Load other children

// Mark list children as deleted
if (!course.Curriculum.Sessions.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    for (int i = course.Curriculum.Sessions.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        var session = course.Curriculum.Sessions[i];
        context.Entry(session).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    }
}

// Remove course
context.Courses.Remove(course);
```

The delete operation ends with an error related to `SessionTime`'s foreign key to the `SessionAttendance` class.

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.SessionAttendances_dbo.SessionTime_Session_Id". The conflict occurred in database "MyDb", table "dbo.SessionAttendances", column 'Session_Id

Since the `SessionAttendance` has a optional `SessionTime`, I'm confused.

What's the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have to delete associated records in the foreign key tables first before removing the record.

From the logic you were writing, you need to add business scenarios to remove SessionAttendances rows that contain the `Session_Id` before removing the `Session` record.